# Facebook login - Javascript SDK + Reading cookie from server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, jakarta-ee, cookies, facebook-javascript-sdk

Our website (Java server side) uses Facebook Javascript SDK for login. We enable the cookie creation and then on the server side we are trying to read the cookie to make a call to Graph API.

The steps we follow are:
- Retrieve the facebook cookie based on Facebook API id from HttpRequest
- Decode the cookie to retrieve the code
- Make a HTTP GET request to Facebook Graph to retrieve access token by passing client id, secret, code and redirect uri

I am getting an error at the last step where it says the redirect uri doesn't match the one passed when retrieving the code. What should the redirect uri match?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this from here: http://tech.sociablelabs.com/2011/09/19/server-side-changes-facebook-oauth-2-0-upgrade/

It turns out that the redirect_uri is empty string as set by Facebook Javascript SDK.